# Two users for one workspace in Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs

Is it possible for two users (each user with his own computer) to work on one workspace in Team Foundation Server?

How can I set my remote workspace? The workspace that I create on my computer is not being displayed on my friend's computer, yet we are both on the same network and my computer is the one where the Team Foundation Server is installed.

All I what is to prevent project members to copy the code sources(copying). What I understand is for project members to work on the project they need a workspace on the computer and that workspace maps a folder of team project. When a workspace maps a folder all the mapped folder files and folders are being downlaod on the members computer a part from the folder that they cloacked when their creating the workspace.

the team foundation server is installed on my computer (running windows 7).

Comment: This may be possible, but it's a very uncommon configuration.  Can you better explain why would you want to do this?  Why would you not both simply have your own workspace?

Comment: @EdwardThomson I've updated the question with the reply (it was posted as an answer and deleted.)

Comment: All I what is to prevent project members to copy the code sources(copying). What I understand is for project members to work on the project they need a workspace on the computer and that workspace maps a folder of team project. When a workspace maps a folder all the mapped folder files and folders are being downlaod on the members computer a part from the folder that they cloacked when their creating the workspace.

the team foundation server is installed on my computer (running windows 7).